# Create window Service from a batch file?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, nginx

I have a batch file name start_all_service.bat contain the below code

```
@ECHO OFF
taskkill /f /IM nginx.exe
taskkill /f /IM php-cgi.exe
@ECHO OFF
c:\nginx\nginx.exe
REM c:\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\php\php.ini
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1>NUL
echo Starting nginx
echo .
echo .
echo .
ping 127.0.0.1 >NUL
c:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:\nginx\php\php.ini
echo php-cgi.exe has started
```

I need to make this batch file as an window service.

Answer (score 0):

Since your script doesn't loop or stay running, why not make a scheduled task that runs at startup? One-time actions are not really services.

Comment: I need to make as an service so that if i need to start or stop the service i can do that.

Comment: What does it mean to stop the "service" represented by the script? It doesn't look like the script continues to run. I don't know what nginx is, but if the `echo` statement at the end is ever executed, then the script can't possibly run as a service because it ends. Do you want to make a service out of nginx (and not the batch script)?